# Combining Selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given the following HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr id="row1">
    <td class="CommandLinks">
      <input type="checkbox" class="CommandLinks" />
    </td>
    <td class="Class2">
      <input type="text" value="1">
    </td>
    <td class="Class3">
      <input type="text" value="1">
    </td>
    <td class="Class4">
      <input type="text" value="1">
    </td>
    <td class="Class5">
      <input type="text" value="1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
    ...
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

I can obtain the first checkbox using:

```
var row = $('tr#row1');
var checkbox = row.find('input[data-trackingid]');
```

However, it occurs to me that there is a little bit of extra overhead as jQuery has to scan every cell in the row. I was thinking about something like `row.find('tr[class=CommandLinks] > input[data-trackingid]')` but I see that doesn't work.

How could I modify the query above so that it only looks in `$('tr[class=CommandLinks]')`?

*Note: I realize there are other ways to find this checkbox, but in my actual application I want to search by the attribute, as shown above.*

Comment: `$('td#row1');` -> `$('tr#row1');`?

Comment: `$('td#row1');` looks invalid since there's no td element with that ID (`$('#row1');` should suffice since IDs must be unique), and I see no data attribute in your example.

Comment: Right you are. Corrected.

Comment: @good4m: Yes, perhaps, however I may want to handle cases where there are more than one.

Comment: im not sure why you wouldn't just do $('td.CommandLinks');

Comment: @iAmClownShoe: In my real code, I already have the row and I'm working with that.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? What's the point ?

Comment: @JonathanWood but what's the point of storing the row in a variable first? if you really want to use the row: $('tr#row1 td.CommandLinks'); can you explain what reason you have in your "real" code to be storing row in a variable first and then using that to traverse its children elements?

Comment: @iAmClownShoe: Again, I already have the row. If you need to know, my code has just copied this row and now I need to modify it. Either way, I already have the row.

Comment: @Siamak.A.M: I'm not sure how else to say it. I want to combine those two selectors in my argument to `find()`. The results of that, if possible, would be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: related post ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950888/how-to-tell-jquery-to-stop-searching-dom-when-the-first-element-is-found

Comment: @Xander: I don't see how that is the same question.

Comment: @JonathanWood not the same, *similar,* in that you're trying to improve performance by not searching the entire "haystack."

Comment: i think this would be a lot easier to answer if we could understand exactly what it is you're trying to do here. im definitely confused by this and am not sure what you're end goal is. you want to find the td with a class name that's a child of the row you grab in the row variable so you can modify the row? pls clarify

Comment: also, this bit `... tr[class=CommandLinks] ...` won't work. there is no `tr` with a class of `CommandLinks` ...

Comment: @Xander: Yes, that was in fact my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var row = $('tr#row1');
var checkbox = row.find('td.CommandLinks > input[data-trackingid]');
```

If data-trackingid is set on that element.

Or this:

```
var row = $('tr#row1');
var checkbox = row.find('td.CommandLinks').find('> input[data-trackingid]');
```

which is equivalent in jQuery.

Comment: Yes! Your first version is what I was looking for. I had tried `row.find('tr[class=CommandLinks] > input[data-trackingid]')`, which didn't work.

Comment: @Huangism what do you mean by that?

Comment: I thought the OP wanted to target $('tr[class=CommandLinks]') probably td instead of tr, for the rest of the rows, but I think he only wants the first one now

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to do `tr#row1`. The ID selector **will only ever look for one**.

Just use the following, you shouldn't have any performance concerns:

```
var checkbox = $('#row1 .CommandLinks input[data-trackingid=foo]');
```

As shown below, it's **slightly** faster, but not by a great deal!

[image: 1]

jsPerf: http://jsperf.com/jquerychildrenperf

Comment: @JonathanWood Included a performance tester, feel free to tweak it.

Comment: Thanks for the performance test. However, my actual page is far more complex. It might not be a huge difference but I'd like to keep things quick when it is easy to make them that way.

Comment: @JonathanWood It might be a good idea to post all your HTML in that test (you can edit it), that way you can see which selector provides the fastest results.

Comment: @mattytommo: for just single statement your observation is ok. 
But if you need to get multiple descendants from single #row1 then you may have different results. Just remember that `$('#row1 .CommandLinks input[data-trackingid=foo]');` scans whole DOM each time you call it. There are some optimizations possible but far not always.